# Is it good practice to have a table referenced by two different entities?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, entity-framework, mocking, wcf-ria-services

I am building a application with these patterns: Silverlight, RIA, EF, Prism, SL Unit Testing.

This project will have lots of entities and lots of modules referencing those entities. Each entity is in its own RIA Service Library along with the RIA domain service and associated metadata.

I am running into problems when I reference a certain table in two different entities. For example table bar exists in entity1 and entity2.

**My Question:** Is it good practice to have the same table in multiple entities (.edmx files)?

If so what are good ways to avoid them causing a mulitple reference error?

If not what do I do when I need that table in another entity?

Comment: I don't get the question.  It's specifically forbidden by your ORM.  Why ask if it's a good practice?  It's forbidden by the tool you chose, so it can't be a good practice.  What do you really want to know?  Do you want to know if you chose the wrong tool?  Do you want to know of another tool will allow this?  It's forbidden, so what are you *really* asking?

Comment: It isn't actually forbidden by the EF, but it's complicated to set up correctly, and certainly not a beginner's technique. That said, the question in the title and the error message he reports are not strictly related, so I think there's more going on here than he lets on. I think it would help if he asked what problem he was actually trying to solve instead of why his attempted solution. For starters, "mock database?" That's almost a contradiction in terms!

Comment: @ Lott 
It is actually not forbidden. I can do it fine but I run into problems if I ever have to reference the two different domain services in the same solution which didnt happen until I tried to mock a DB.

@Stuntz
The error message did have to do with something different but only slightly. It was the fact that I was trying to use an entity from an edmx in two different domain services (the real and the mock). But the ultimate question I have still stands. Since Lott only asked questions and didnt answer my question. Also people mock DB's all the time for unit testing.

Comment: @johnnywhoop: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please clarify, correct or update your question.  It's your question.  You can fix it to be crystal clear.

Comment: @Lott Please answer my question rather than commenting on it telling me I can't do something that I am doing. If it is forbidden where is the documentation on it? A simple answer "No" would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you start working with EF (and most ORMs), you tend towards having an entity-per-table relationship, or at least, a table->entity hierarchy relationship, if you have inheritance in your entities.

If you're trying to refer to the same table from 2 separate entity types, you probably need to pull out a shared, single entity type that's refered to by both of your other entities.